# Matrix dimensions of Derivative of Softmax on Vectorized version

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, softmax

I am trying to get the matrix dimensions right for computing derivative of a two layers network where the last layer is softmax function.

For simplicity I am only interested to get derivatives of W2 w.r.t Loss.
I think for a single input x1, my math works out OK(below) and the dL/dW2 correctly comes same dimension as W2 (DxC). However I struggle on vectorizing it for all inputs X.

In specific, in non-vectorize version the derivative of softmax(here A2) w.r.t its input (here Z2) has dimensions CxC since the function maps [image]. This is explained very well in [this link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/). But what is the dimension of this matrix in vectorized version for all inputs? It cannot be still CxC since that is only for a single input.

I have marked in red where I am not sure what the correct dimensions are. Please if anyone can review my math and post an answer. I know there might be different formulation than what I have done here but I appreciate if you show me where I got it wrong. Thanks.

[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn4O5.png)